# Custom Connection Xero API in Power Automate

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, xero-api, power-platform

I have been trying to connect to Xero through a custom connector on Power Automate but I always get either:

Operation failed (403), or when I include the Tenant ID in the header I get Request failed. Please try again in a few minutes.

Has anyone successful created a custom connector for Xero in Power Automate, and if so what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have created a custom connector in Power Automate which works fine. Are you getting stuck in the step 2. security or 3. definitions? You might have to create a policy to set the tenant-id in the header.